# Ignoring numbers in a file

Tags: java, arrays, file, io, 2d

I am making a program which takes in data from a file and makes a maze game from it. An example maze.txt file would look like:

```
5  5
P.XX.
...X.
.XT..
..X..
X....
```

Where the two numbers on top define the rows and columns of the array.
Here is the code I am using

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MazeGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Display the maze

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("maze.txt"));
        int rows1 = sc.nextInt();
        int columns1 = sc.nextInt();
        rows1 += 1;
        columns1 += 1;

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("maze.txt"));

        char[][] treasureMaze = new char[rows1][columns1];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows1 || i < columns1; ++i) {
            String line = in.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                System.out.println("Error in array");
                return;
            }
            sc.nextLine();

            treasureMaze[i] = line.toCharArray();
        }

        display(treasureMaze);
        int vertical = 0;
        int horizontal = 0;

        // Give Move Options
        options();

        // Setup a while loop that continues until
        // the user has gotten to the treasure, or 'P'
        while (treasureMaze[vertical][horizontal] != 'T') {
            // Get Users Decision
            Scanner moveChoice = new Scanner(System.in);
            int choice = moveChoice.nextInt();

            if (choice == 1) {
                System.out.println("You chose to Move up");
            } else if (choice == 2) {
                System.out.println("You chose to Move down");
            } else if (choice == 3) {
                System.out.println("You chose to Move left");
            } else if (choice == 4) {
                System.out.println("you chose to Move right");
            } else {
                return;
            }

            // Move the Player: Each choice will move the player
            // according to their choice and then re-display the
            // map and options so that they can move through the maze

            // Move Up
            if (choice == 1) {
                if (vertical - 1 < 0) {
                    System.out
                            .println("\nCannot move there! Try something else\n");
                    display(treasureMaze);
                    options();
                } else if (treasureMaze[vertical - 1][horizontal] == '.') {
                    treasureMaze[vertical - 1][horizontal] = 'P';
                    treasureMaze[vertical][horizontal] = '.';
                    vertical -= 1;
                    display(treasureMaze);
                    options();
                } else if (treasureMaze[vertical - 1][horizontal] == 'T') {
                    System.out.println("\nCongratulations you won!");
                    treasureMaze[vertical][horizontal] = 'T';
                } else {
                    System.out
                            .println("\nCannot move there! Try something else\n");
                    display(treasureMaze);
                    options();
                }
            }

            // Move Down
            else if (choice == 2) {
                if (vertical + 1 < 0) {
                    System.out
                            .println("\nCannot move there! Try something else\n");
                    display(treasureMaze);
                    options();
                } else if (treasureMaze[vertical + 1][horizontal] == '.') {
                    treasureMaze[vertical + 1][horizontal] = 'P';
                    treasureMaze[vertical][horizontal] = '.';
                    vertical += 1;
                    display(treasureMaze);
                    options();
                } else if (treasureMaze[vertical + 1][horizontal] == 'T') {
                    System.out.println("\nCongratulations you won!");
                    treasureMaze[vertical][horizontal] = 'T';
                } else {
                    System.out
                            .println("\nCannot move there! Try something else\n");
                    display(treasureMaze);
                    options();
                }
            }

            // Move Left
            else if (choice == 3) {
                if (horizontal - 1 < 0) {
                    System.out
                            .println("\nCannot move there! Try something else\n");
                    display(treasureMaze);
                    options();
                } else if (treasureMaze[vertical][horizontal - 1] == '.') {
                    treasureMaze[vertical][horizontal - 1] = 'P';
                    treasureMaze[vertical][horizontal] = '.';
                    horizontal -= 1;
                    display(treasureMaze);
                    options();
                } else if (treasureMaze[vertical][horizontal - 1] == 'T') {
                    System.out.println("\nCongratulations you won!");
                    treasureMaze[vertical][horizontal] = 'T';
                } else {
                    System.out
                            .println("\nCannot move there! Try something else\n");
                    display(treasureMaze);
                    options();
                }
            }

            // Move Right
            else if (choice == 4) {
                if (horizontal + 1 < 0) {
                    System.out
                            .println("\nCannot move there! Try something else\n");
                    display(treasureMaze);
                    options();
                } else if (treasureMaze[vertical][horizontal + 1] == '.') {
                    treasureMaze[vertical][horizontal + 1] = 'P';
                    treasureMaze[vertical][horizontal] = '.';
                    horizontal += 1;
                    display(treasureMaze);
                    options();
                } else if (treasureMaze[vertical][horizontal + 1] == 'T') {
                    System.out.println("\nCongratulations you won!");
                    treasureMaze[vertical][horizontal] = 'T';
                } else {
                    System.out
                            .println("\nCannot move there! Try something else\n");
                    display(treasureMaze);
                    options();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Bye!");
                return;
            }

        }
    }

    // Display Object: prints out the maze for the user
    public static void display(char x[][]) {
        for (int row = 0; row < x.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < x[row].length; column++) {
                System.out.print(x[row][column] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    // Options Object: gives the options menu to the user
    static void options() {
        System.out.println("You may:");
        System.out.println("\t1) Move up");
        System.out.println("\t2) Move down");
        System.out.println("\t3) Move left");
        System.out.println("\t4) Move right");
        System.out.println("\t0) Quit");

    }
}
```

When I try to run the program, I need to see the `5  5` for the first run and then get rid of it so that I can use the rest of my program without running into the numbers on top. Is there a way to ignore these numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use [Scanner.nextLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) Instead of opening the file again with a BufferedReader.

EDIT:

To clarify, I mean:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("maze.txt"));
    int rows1 = sc.nextInt();
    int columns1 = sc.nextInt();

    char[][] treasureMaze = new char[rows1][columns1];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows1; ++i) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
```

EDIT2:

I removed

```
    rows1 += 1;
    columns1 += 1;
```

and changed the for loop:

I'm not sure what the purpose of adding 1 to rows and columns was and the loop should really only loop over the number of rows `rows1`.  At least for the reading in the file part.

Comment: yes that is what I did. I still receive an error. "No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)" is what I get

Comment: The `rows1 += 1` meant that you tried to read more lines than are available in the file in your for loop...

Comment: I still seem to be getting the same error. Any chance you know why its happening?

Comment: @beny23, what you are missing is that the OP has a superfluous `sc.nextLine` in the for loop. This is a homework assignment, so I wouldn't go too much further in details.

Comment: @TimBender: hehe, I hadn't read much further in the code than the initial readLine [puts glasses back on]

Answer (score 1):

Why are you opening the file to read twice?

> Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("maze.txt"));
>   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("maze.txt"));

Either use a `Scanner` or a `BufferedReader`, not both.

Another option is to simply call `BufferedReader.readLine` an extra time in the beginning to ignore the first line.

With the least code changed, you can actually pass a String to construct a Scanner:

```
    //move BufferedReader creation up
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("maze.txt"));
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(in.readLine()); //Scan first line from the Reader

    // The res tof your code as it exists now
    int rows1 = sc.nextInt();
    int columns1 = sc.nextInt();
    rows1 += 1;
    columns1 += 1;
```

Comment: This still gives me an error it is saying that it can't find a line: "No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)"

Comment: delete that line, it is useless. `|| i < columns1` is also useless.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a similar scenario but my code is completely diffrent from yours. if you wanna just ignore the numbers on line 1, you can simply do a check before you proceed to the next line.
check this code :

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter rows and columns");
    PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter("maze.txt");
    write.println(scan.next());
    write.print("a bc db gj");
    write.flush();
    write.close();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("maze.txt"));
    String rt="";
    while((rt=reader.readLine())!=null) {
        if(rt.startsWith("5")) {
         continue;  
        }
        else {
        System.out.println(rt);
        }
    }

}
```

Input:

5 5

OUTPUT:a bc db gj

hope this helps :)